# what do red and green bars at bitcoinity.org mean?

Tags: charts

The changebars graph at http://bitcoinity.org has red and green bars. Some of them below and some above zero.

What is their meaning?

- If they are above zero

  - and are green
  - and are red
- if they are below zero

  - and are green
  - and are red?

Is there a wikipedia article about that kind of graph? What would the search term be?

The rest of the graph is explained here https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbXtB.png but not the red and green bars.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're answering your own question, please put it as an answer and select it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the WTF on the upper right corner you get explanations for all of the graphs. But not yet for the bars being below or above zero. The author will add that soon (2013-03-23).

Meanwhile you can look at a reddit question here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1aqtgo/a_note_for_newbies_about_market_forces_feel_free/c8zz2ro

- green bars above the axis represent increases in buy/bid orders
- red bars below the axis represent decreases in buy/bid orders
- red bars above the axis represent increases in sell/ask orders
- green bars below the axis represent decreases in sell/ask orders

(I think you can replace *axis* and *above/below* by *current price* and *right/left*, then it is correct. Though this does not explain the bars above and below the line parallel to the x axis)

Well, I didn’t completely understand, why they are above and below, but I understood from the WTF explanation on the site, what red and green means. tl;dr: Green has different meaning, if it is left of the current price or if it is right of the current price. Same for red bars.

Maybe *comboy*, the author of that site, adds a good explanation for this soon (he promised to do so on freenode irc chat).